# problem while fetching Facebook android-sdk from github

Tags: github

i want to add facebook sdk in my android sdk with eclipse(windows 7). i am trying with  https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk this url to fetch the repository. But it shows no file found at the location, Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch is using Git or what have you tried?

Comment: question is about "Drop-down list in android" , is make any sense with problem description??

Comment: This seems to be just a git-on-Windows question; it doesn't have anything to do with Android. If you're having trouble figuring out how to check out a github repo's code (and not trouble with *using* the code), I suggest checking out Github's helpful help pages: http://help.github.com/ for more info on how to use git in general.

Answer (score 0):

how did you fetch the repository? can you edit your post and add the command that you use.

you can clone the source code by using the following command
`git clone git://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git`

off topic: why do you use Windows? wouldn't be easier to use a mac or a linux box?

Comment: hoe to clone friend ? i mean where we have to use this command ? in GitBash ? or where ?